# Rename many files in different folder sequentially

Tags: file, applescript, directory, rename

i have a folder that contains like 700 subfolders in a specific order ( folder 0, folder 1, etc. ) in this subfolders there are some different images in an oder specific order ( 0.jpg, 1.jpg, etc. ). I would like make a script that can rename all this images sequentially from zero and move all them to a single folder but keeping the order of all files. I tried several times with programs and automator workflows but i need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running something like this in Terminal:

`cd ~/containing_directory; i=0; printf %s\\n */*.jpg | sed 's/folder //' | sort -n -t/ -k1,1 -k2,2 | while read f; do mv "folder $f" $((i++)).jpg; done`

If the directories and files were named like `folder 001/file 001.jpg`, you could just use a for loop:

`i=0; for f in */*.jpg; do mv "$f" $((i++)).jpg; done`